# Fomatting the Highcharts date with correct month

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a Json Data which i am retrieving from Database for populating the highcharts series 
the series data retrieving from DB looks like this.
`'series_data' => string '[ 
{name:'Hyderabad',data:[
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 01),311328],[Date.UTC(2013, 05, 02),363780],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 04, 03),364062],[Date.UTC(2013, 04, 04),283128],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 04, 05),322608]] },
{name:'Vijayawada',data:[
    [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 01),363216],[Date.UTC(2013, 06, 02),404670],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 03),370783],[Date.UTC(2013, 06, 04),459942],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 07, 05),569499]] }]'` 


 There is a problem with the javascript Date while showing in the chart, It is showing One month ahead.
I know javascipt Date will accept the month value 0 - 11... 0 is the january and 11 is the December,


So, here my question is, while showing in the highchart how to format the date to show the correct month. I cant format the date in DB side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to format dates in database, but you can format it before sending to Highcharts.

Simple instead of:

```
Date.UTC(2013, 05, 01)
```

Use:

```
Date.UTC(2013, 04, 01)
```

Or even better:

```
Date.UTC(2013, 4, 1)
```

Solution in JS:

```
function subtractMonth(a) {
    var date = new Date(a[0]),
        month = date.getMonth();

    date.setMonth(month - 1);

    return [date.getTime(), a[1]];
}

function sorter(a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
}

var data = [{
    name: 'Hyderabad',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 01), 311328],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 02), 363780],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 04, 03), 364062],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 04, 04), 283128],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 04, 05), 322608]
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Vijayawada',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 01), 363216],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 02), 404670],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 03), 370783],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 06, 04), 459942],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 07, 05), 569499]
    ]
}];

$.each(data, function (i, s) {
    s.data = s.data.map(subtractMonth);
    s.data.sort(sorter);
})



$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'    
    },
    series: data
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9nR2/

Comment: Is there any solution in highcharts library itself?

Comment: See my answer above, Highcharts has lots of ways to format dates

Comment: @t1nr2y Thank You man.. but that doesnt help.. how can I format the json data with Highcharts.dataFormat function.

Comment: I don't think there is great solution for that - simply months are different number of days, so how would you remove milliseconds to get previous month? Of course, there is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/n9nR2/, but to be honest, it doesn't looks quite good. Note: I have added sorter, becuase Highcharts requires data to be sorted by x-values. Added as answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not need to format the date within the data itself. Highcharts has specific configurations for formatting the dates, called dateFormat. They have them for labels and tooltips. Then if you were doing something custom after the chart was created, you might need to do it yourself, but usually not they way you are doing it. Please see these Highcharts API links for examples:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat